# What do I need to understand this article

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I've just finished [Fulton's algebraic curves book](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~wfulton/CurveBook.pdf) and I would like to know what do I need to know to understand this [article](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416).

I need some bibliography.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Suggested algorithm: 1) Read until you get stuck. 2) Look in Arbarello--Cornalba--Griffiths--Harris until you understand what you were stuck on. 3) Goto 1.